# Blender adds 180 degrees to rotation, messing up my animation

Tags: animation, transforms

Sometimes when I move an object, Blender decides to add 180 degrees to the rotation, which is very annoying because the animation then does a 360 from the previous keyframe, even though it wasn't supposed to rotate at all.

In the first one here I can move it just fine, in the second rotation, as soon as I select the object and hit 'G' to move, it flips the rotation. The only way around that which I have now is doing the rest of the animation entirely by moving around values on the graph editor...

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have some keyframes that are off? reset them and rerecord?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'keyframe being off'.

Comment: if you accidentally incorrectly keyed something. could you take a small vid of the problem? that might help

Comment: That is a common problem with euler rotation, but to tell more, it would be helpful if you could share your blend file.

Comment: I made a quick video showing it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nzpf4-hjCHQ\

I've run into this problem before but I really want to understand it this time to avoid it. The weird thing is that it doesn't happen with non animated objects and the same transform.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really see the problem from the video. Unfortunately I am not a psychic. But I may have misunderstood you, and it is displayed correctly anyway, only the Euler angles flip strangely (and that's why you can't animate them directly). In that case, I would take a closer look at the topic [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). Blender tries to avoid exactly this problem, which is why it sometimes comes to a strange constellation of Euler angles.